# Hibernate auto populate foreign key in composite id

Tags: hibernate, foreign-keys

I have two tables (columns):
PARENT (P_ID_PK, AUTO_INCREMENT), and 
CHILD (P_ID_FK, C_NAME  (PK=P_ID+C_NAME))

They have one-to-many relation. When I persist parent and child objects, the P_ID_PK has auto_incremented values, but P_ID_FK only has the default value (0). How can I have P_ID_FK to have the same values as P_ID_PK? Here is my code:

```
@Entity
@Tabler (name="PARENT")
public class Parent {
  @ID
  @Column (name = "P_ID_PK")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.Identity)
  private Integer pIdPk;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
  @JoinColumn (name = "P_ID_PK")
  private List<Child> children;
  //...getters setters, constructors 
 }

@Embeddable
public class ChildId implements Serializable {
  private Integer pIdFk;
  private String cName;

  @Column(name="P_ID_FK")
  public Integer getPIdFk(){
  return this.pIdFk;}

  @Column(name="C_NAME")
  public String getCName(){
  return this.cName;}
  //... setters, @Override hashCode(),equals()
}

@Entity
@Table(name="CHILD")
public class Child {
  @EmbeddedId
  @AttributeOverrides({
     @AttributeOverride (name="pIdFk", column=@Column(name="P_ID_FK")),
     @AttributeOverride (name="cName", column=@Column(name="C_NAME"))})
 private ChildId childId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn (name="P_ID_FK", referencedColumnName="P_ID_PK")
private Parent parent;
 //... Constructors, getters and setters 
}

test:
{
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

Parent p = new Parent();
List<Child> cs = new Arraylist<Child>();
ChildId cId = new ChildId();
cId.setCName("xxx");
Child C = new Child();
c.setChildId(cId);
c.setParent(p);
cs.add(c);
p.setChildren(cs);

session.save(p);
System.out.println("pIdPk= "+p.getPIdPk());
System.out.println("pIdFk= "+p.getChidren().get(0).getPIdFk);
....
}

Output:
pIdPk= Auto_incremented values (works well)
pIdFk= 0 (Problem: how to have the same value as pIdPk?)
```

Comment: Use MapsId: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html, http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e2401

Comment: http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/09/26/jpa-mapsid-example/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. It seems MapsId is the way. I actually found a good example in the following link: http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/09/26/jpa-mapsid-example/.    But, I still couldn't have my case work. As in the linked example, if I first  persist the parent table, I can get the P_ID_PK value, so I can just set explicitly the P_ID_FK (in the child table) to the value, and then persist the child table. But this seems not to be the way that Hibernate should do.

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, it seems impossible to auto populate the foreign key which is part of the composite key. I found two ways to work around: 1) first persist the parent, then read the pk value, set the fk value and persist the child; 2) use ElementCollection.